# How to play movie file from the web with NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am saving a ".mov" file to a hosted Parse database from an image picker controller with data:

```
NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
```

I later retrieve the NSData for the file and would like to let the user play the video using the MPMoviePlayerController.  Is there a way to do this without writing the file?  I would prefer to just play it in a temp location that is released once it has finished...

This is my code but no video plays when the view appears...

```
NSString *outputPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"temp.mov"];

[self.videoData writeToFile:outputPath atomically:YES];
NSURL *moveUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:moveUrl];
[player prepareToPlay];
[player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 197, 240, 160)];
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
```

Comment: By "temp location" do you mean RAM or the *Caches* folder?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the [MPMoviePlayerController is deprecated in iOS9](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW7).
If you really want to use it anyway (not recommended), it has to be initialized using `initWithContentURL:`.
In your case, the best directory would probably be the tmp directory, see [here](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/where-to-store-files).

Comment: Thank you for the links, they were very helpful.  However, unfortunately, no video plays when following the documentation.  I have updated with my code above.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you first get the Data and then play the video. You could stream it depending on your host's bandwidth costs.

Here is a Swift technique to add a video player to a UIView layer, and it loops when done in the notification Selector. (Check how to use Swift with Objective-C if you dont want to convert it)

> import AVFoundation

```
var videoPlayer: AVPlayer!
var isMoviePlaying: Bool = false

func playVideo(video: Video, autoplay: Bool)
{
     if !isMoviePlaying
        {
            isMoviePlaying = true
            var url:NSURL = NSURL(string: videoUrl)!

            startActivityIndicator()

            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: url)

            self.videoPlayer = AVPlayer.playerWithPlayerItem(playerItem) as! AVPlayer

            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerItemDidReachEnd:", name:"AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification", object: videoPlayer.currentItem)

            let layer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.videoPlayer)
            self.videoPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .None

            layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width * 0.95, self.frame.size.height * 0.85)
            layer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(layer)

            stopActivityIndicator()

            self.videoPlayer.play()
        }
}


func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification)
{
    // loop the video
    if let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem
    {
        playerItem.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    }
}
```